# How to create a function that change is_active=False to True?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to create a function that change `is_active=False` to `True`?
The case is that I want to create a function that change the value in an user case from `is_active=False` to `is_active=True`. At my final point I want to create "an email verification" when someone registered. If someone registered on my website, he receive an email with the verification.

I guess I have to create a function that change "is_active=false" on "is_active=true" when someone clicked the link that call the function? Mean I well?

Thanks!

```
def activateEmail(request, user, email, first_name):
    send_mail(
        #email subject
        f"Activate your user account, {user.first_name} !",
        #email content
        f"Hi {user.first_name}!\nPlease click on the link below to confirm your registration\n{SITE_URL}\nhttps://patronite.pl/wizard/autor/profil?step=3",
        #email host user
        EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        #email to
        [user.email],
        #if error True is better.
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Comment: What is `is_active`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a function something like this

```
def register_confirm(request, activation_key):

if request.user.is_authenticated():
   
  HttpResponseRedirect('/home')

user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, 
                   activation_key=activation_key)

if user_profile.key_expires < timezone.now():
    return render_to_response('user_profile/confirm_expired.html')
user = user_profile.user
user.is_active = True
user.save()
return render_to_response('user_profile/confirm.html')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.